# Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proxy

i am facing this issue in my pc, also in my colleges pc, neither of any library is downloading, i have selected no proxy option from settings moreover also add this in my gradle.properties file, but still facing this issue.

```
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully resolved this error, it was due to proxy in domain.